# Rate of change of position vector of point on a circle with a twist

Tags: calculus, geometry, differential-geometry, vectors

I am wondering how I would calculate the x & y components of a position vector of a point on a circle of radius 1, where:

- the origin of the position vector is at the bottom of the circle (or the bottom of the circle is at point (0,0) on the x-y axis)
- the position vector is rotating counterclockwise at a given constant angular velocity or rate of change of angle, from 0 to 180 degrees

Picture a circle of radius 1 on the x-y plane, such that its center is coincident with the y-axis and the bottom of the circle is tangent to the x-axis. The origin of the position vector is at origin of x-y plane.

Comment: Clarification requested: do you intend that $\tan(\theta) = \frac{y}{x}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the center of the unit circle is (0,1), then the position vector   with given angular velocity $\omega$ :

$\vec{OP}\\$ = $\vec{OA}+\vec{AP}$=$<0,1>+<\cos \omega t,\sin \omega t$>= <$\cos \omega t,1+\sin \omega t>$

[image]